# Shopware 6 search by invoice number

Tags: shopware, shopware6

Is it possible to search by invoice number? When I search by invoice ID, I want to display the invoice. The document number is already selected in the search preferences. For example when i search by 2090, I want to display the invoice.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The search in the admin panel only comprises the entities which you see in the drop down. This includes orders, but not documents.

Adding other entities to the admin search is described [in the German forum](https://forum.shopware.com/t/add-custom-entity-to-administration-search-suche-fehlt/69357/2).

You could add a provider for the search using `Application.addServiceProviderDecorator`.

There is not really a document listing route, as documents are displayed as a part of the orders. So you could reuse the one for the orders and just display the matching orders when an associated document matches. Or you create another listing for all documents.

Another approach would be to extend the matching for orders in the backend and also search for document numbers.